# How can I install Linux from a partition instead of DVD or USB Drive?

Tags: linux, installation, partitioning

When you want to install Linux you usually have the following options:

- use a DVD / CD
- use a Virtual Environment ([Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads))
- use an USB Drive ([UNetbootin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin))

But what if I want to make a separate partition on my HDD, mount the Linux installer ISO on it, select that partition in the bootloader and run it from there? How can I do that? If there are any reasons why I shouldn't install any OS like this, let me know why.

Comment: Do you already have a convenient boot loader installed on that machine? (the Windows one / Lilo / Grub ...)

Comment: I have Grub 2 installed

Comment: Then you can copy the files inside the ISO to disk and configure Grub to boot with those files. Google "Install linux from hard disk"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I install windows using a virtual disk drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/558959/can-i-install-windows-using-a-virtual-disk-drive)

Answer (score 0):

One reason you might not want to use this sort of configuration is a difference in filesystems; because while Linux can read and write to NTFS partitions, Windows cannot (without third-party software) read or write to any type of filesystem aside from FAT or NTFS. Additionally, while as I mentioned there IS a selection of third-party software out there which WILL allow you to access EXT2/3/4 partitions, that software is far from perfect and in many cases will only increase the risk of damaging the data on those partitions.

I know personal opinions are somewhat frowned upon by the moderators, but here's my $0.02 anyways. You would be much better served running Linux in a virtual machine.

Comment: Huh? The OP just wants to install Linux without using a USB or CD. That has nothing to do with whether or not the resulting system will be accessible from Windows.

Comment: @terdon is right, what does NTFS support have to do with the OP's question? As long as Grub or any other boot loader/manager can boot from the ISO (as-is or extracted), the files can be on an ext4 partition for all anyone cares.