# How can I (re)install Ubuntu from within Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, reinstall

How can I (re)install Ubuntu from within Ubuntu?

I am running Ubuntu 12.04, and I have a Ubuntu 13.04 on a USB drive.

I want to format my hard drive and install Ubuntu 13.04. I don't have a CD, and my computer won't boot from USB.

Comment: You can use GRUB like in my answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/558959/can-i-install-windows-using-a-virtual-disk-drive

Answer (score 0):

From [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279620/how-do-i-upgrade-from-12-10-to-13-04):

To upgrade from Ubuntu 12.10 on a desktop system:

- Open Software Sources.
- Switch to the Updates tab and set Notify me of a new Ubuntu version to For any new       version.
- Press Alt+F2 and type in "update-manager -d" (without the quotes) into the command box.
- Update Manager should open up and tell you: New distribution release '13.04' is available.
- Click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions.

No need for USB device.
However, if you don't have internet connection it won't work.

Comment: Does that allow me to format, or is that just an upgrade?

Comment: I am not sure, but it makes sense that it will ask you if you want to format. Actually I have dual-boot laptop with Ubuntu 12.04, so I will check this now.

Comment: Also, have you tried changing the boot order via the boot menu? it should let you boot from USB.

Comment: Yea I tried changing the boot order, there was a "Removable Media" option, but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you determine your motherboard model and write it here?
By the way, Ubuntu Upgrade doesn't have the option of formatting, I've checked.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do a format and install without booting from some external device.

Comment: Can I not make Ubuntu boot from the USB? or Grub maybe?

Comment: Booting from USB will be a bios option in your PC, it won't be anything to do with the operating system you're trying to boot into.